# Display YUV/RGB frames on FFPLAY window

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rendering, yuv, libavcodec

I have integrated a custom decoder on `FFMPEG` framework. The output of this decoder is YUV420 frames, which if required i can convert it to RGB24 frames.

These frames are generated in one of my custom functions. So in order to render these frames on `FFPLAY` window what has to be done? Is there any specific syntax or procedure to follow?

I'm really new to `FFPLAY` and have searched enough over this topic on net, but have not got anything related to this issue. If anyone can provide any answers or suggestions regarding this, it will be of great help to me.

Thanks in advance.

--Regards

Comment: Are you trying to play a file or piped input? If a file please provide a short sample. Are you using the ffplay cli-tool or are you using programatically?

Comment: If you have written a new decoder for FFmpeg that outputs YUV 4:2:0 natively, then FFplay should just be able to play the video without any modification. Are you sure you are communicating the colorspace from your decoder to the core engine?

Comment: @MultimediaMike: Thanks for the reply. I was waiting for a reply like this. Yes i in my native code i.e. C-code, I'm able to generate a YUV 420 frame. However as i have told you i'm really new to this ffplay thing, I have now idea regarding : How to communicate the colorspace from my decoder to the core engine. Any document or any article that can give me an idea regarding this please post it as a reply here and i shall accept it. --Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on hacking codecs for FFmpeg, but I just checked out the latest git source and I'm assuming that you are working from the same copy. I am further assuming that you inserted your decoder alongside the rest of the codecs in the libavcodec/ directory and that when you build the program and run `ffmpeg -formats`, you see your new decoder mentioned.

If this is all true, then I will assume that your decoder module exports an init() function which expects to receive a pointer to a `AVCodecContext` function. This data structure has a member named pix_fmt and this should be set to AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P in your decoder's case in order to indicate planar YUV 4:2:0.

If this doesn't work, try using the `ffmpeg` tool to decode the file to the null target, just to test that your decoder is doing something:

```
ffmpeg -i yourfile.ext -f null /dev/null
```

Amend your question with the output from this command to give us further clues.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have my decoder with the init, but i had not specified the pixel fmt variable. When given the command ffmpeg --decoders, i get to see my decoder name in the list. But should i not map this output frame to something like SDL frame (coz ffplay used SDL libraries)? And as i said the YUV frame generate in not in the same flow as other decoder. Can you please throw some light on this issue? (i mean SDL mapping)

Comment: The video decoder shouldn't need any knowledge of the video output layer. The decoder should just decode to the most efficient pixel format (planar YUV 4:2:0), pass the frame back to the engine, and let the engine figure out what to do with it. The output could be an SDL window, or an X11 window, or an OpenGL surface, or a file on disk.Put another way: a basic H.264 video (find an MP4 file) should play with ffplay. The H.264 video decoder outputs planar YUV 4:2:0 data and then passes it back to the engine, which then sends it to SDL. This is how your decoder should behave, too.

Comment: Its just amazing... The explanation you just provided. Thanks a lot :-)